# CSS: how to horizontally center this particular element on the page?

Tags: css

I have a page with tab navigation at the top ([page here](http://putitouttherepictures.com/dev/what-we-do/); tabs are 'Production,' 'Story and Development,' etc).  I would like to ensure the row of tabs are horizontally centered on the page.  How can I accomplish that?  If I'm not mistaken, it's currently *a tad* off center.

By following the instructions on the [W3 Schools page on CSS centering](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp), I came close by setting:

```
display: block;
margin: auto;
width: 99%;
```

But I'm not sure if that's the proper/best solution. Is there a solution that does not require setting `width: 99%`?

If it matters, the site has been built with WordPress.

Thanks.

Comment: 99% is safe assuming that all browser defaults for margins and padding still apply.

Comment: have you tried flex ?  Something like: `.ut-nav-tabs{display:flex;justify-content:center;}.ut-nav-tabs li {margin:0 1px;}` ?

Comment: the flex method shold work for you, you  can just use  above style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways you could approach this:

**The `text-align: center` Method**

```
.ut-nav-tabs li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.ut-nav-tabs li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.ut-nav-tabs {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This works only if you declare `text-align: center` on the containing parent - the parent element must be a *block element*. The nested children elements must be *inline block* elements (e.g: `display: inline-block`) with no `float` rules declared on them, `float`s will negate any attempt to horizontally center align elements this way, and most other ways.

**The `display: flex` Method**

```
.ut-nav-tabs {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.ut-nav-tabs li {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

This is the "new kid" on the block and the "hot fix" for any alignment issue concerning CSS these days, I would hazard to say it is the "jQuery" of CSS now.
Anyway, it is for good reason, `flex-box` rules allows you to specify general alignment (horizontally and vertically) and lets the browser do all the calculations for precise positioning - this is also why is a popular responsive solution too.

**Browser Compatibility:** A heads-up though, `flex-box` has poor or very limited support for legacy browsers, older browsers may give you unexpected results, so you should use this with caution in production code if that will be a concern.

Comment: OK thanks, that worked.  I went with the `text-align: center` method because of your warning about limited support for `flex-box.`  If both methods work just as fine, I'll stick with the one with slightly more support.  One small lingering issue is with the layout at lower screen widths.  The elements become *slightly* out of alignment (screenshot:  https://imgur.com/uTIaT0D).  You can see it especially ~445 px screen widths.  Thoughts on that?

Comment: Good call. Those are your margins you have declared on your list items, you can remove them altogether, or declare rules like this: `.ut-nav-tabs li:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: 0px;
}` for those resolutions. You may have to adjust rules in this manner for a few resolutions scaling down - that's just part of responsive design (but that goes beyond the scope of this question). You can handle this by setting `@media` breakpoints to declare new rules you'll need for the screen sizes you set (*e.g:* `@media (max-width: 445px)`)

Comment: **See:** https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: OK understood on all.  I'll work on the responsiveness separately.  Let's consider this question answered then.

Answer (score 0):

I think this way is better :

```
.ut-nav-tabs {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.ut-nav-tabs li {
    width: 179px;
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I went with the solution proposed by @UncaughtTypeError.  It worked, but also, I was a little hesitant to use the `zoom` property.  I'd never seen it, so I researched it a little.  This page (https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/) kind of scared me away from using it.  What was your motivation for using it?  Was it indeed to resolve rendering issues in IE (as the article mentions)?